# Possible to delete empty macros in Word - or prevent them?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am in the process of creating a series of templates and companion macros and styles (embedded in the template) for different users that perform the same functions (but different results within an individual template).

As an example, every template will have a series of macros that change the font colors in the styles, flip-flopping at will between the default black and various colors, as a visual aid in proofing the formatting.

In another example, every template will have similarly overlapping styles and style names and macros. But the "Question" style for one template, for example, might have the Q at the left margin, with a .5" hanging indent, while another template might start the Q with a first-line indent at 1" and wrap subsequent lines to the margin. But both styles will have the same name. And the companion macros in the templates will also have identical names.

Some macros will be assigned to keyboard shortcuts, but for many of them, the user will either press Alt+F8 to get to the macro list or use a text expander command function to access them (e.g., qcol might run the macro COLORS_Question_Style_Red, which changes the Question style to the red font. The text expander command would do the same thing the user would do: Alt+F8, COLORS_Question_Style_Red, [ENTER].

All that works just fine, except when the user forgets that she is not in a document based on one of them templates, and she goes through the process to invoke the macro (e.g., using the text expander shortcut, or pressing Alt+F8, typing part of the macro name, and pressing ENTER).

Of course, when Word doesn't find such a macro, it assumes you want to *create* one, and it brings you to the macro editor window of the current active template, where it has created an empty macro, which you can now fill in with code. Some users will delete the empty macro when they see it, and others will just close the window, leaving the empty macro intact.

If the user opts to leave the empty macro intact when closing the editor window, the next time she goes through those same erroneous steps of attempting to trigger a macro that isn't currently accessible, the system won't "bother her" by dragging her into the editor window because it believes it has found the macro. But the result will be that it does absolutely nothing, and she'll eventually realize her error and open or create a document based on the proper template(s).

That's all fine and dandy, except for the fact that when she really does want to use a macro in the *proper* template that now also exists in "empty" form in the Normal template, and she goes to run the macro, nothing happens because the empty macro in the Normal template trumps the real macro in the current template.

Additionally, if she attempts to assign a customized keyboard shortcut (in the proper template) to the pseudo-duplicated macro while things are in this state, the macro will not even show up in the Macros/Commands list in the Customize Keyboard dialog window.

I have searched exhaustively in Google and cannot find a single reference to macro code that automatically deletes empty macros. Everything I search for returns hits for deleting empty cells in Excel or a Word table.

Is anyone aware of any code that can be written to address this? I'm thinking it would be good to include it as an Auto_New and Auto_Open macro, as well as provide it for the user to run on demand, as needed during an editing session.

Or maybe there's a better way. I'm open to suggestions. Thanks in advance!

---

UPDATED 1/23/18 to include screen shot of macro window:

[image]

Comment: Why not protect your code so as to prevent users adding macros into your template?

Comment: Hi, Lisa - I actually intend to allow them to add macros to the template for various beneficial purposes relative to the production of these documents, although I don't anticipate a frequent need to do so.

But the bigger problem is that it's not the template macros that are an issue. It's the fact that if you're not in a document based on the template, the macro gets created in whatever template is active at the moment (most likely Normal.dotm), and the empty macro in Normal.dotm takes priority. I can't remove their privilege to create macros in their own Normal template, nor would I. :)

Comment: I think you are trying to achieve something I had done 3 years ago - Create macro-enabled Word templates that shares core macro like changing Styles etc. And this core template (as an AddIn) has all the macro less the custom styles, UI. The child templates has all it's side of Styles/UI and upon opening, the Core template will also be opened if not already opened. The custom UI is customised to each other Template. Too much to explain here.

Comment: Which version of Word is this? On my installation (2010) none of the buttons are active except "Cancel" when I type in a non-existent macro name...

Comment: Hi, @CindyMeister - I am using Office 365/Word 2016. I have edited my original post to include a screen shot of the macro window with Create as the default and only option (invoked by the ENTER key) if there is no macro to match the current string of characters in the macro name window.

Comment: Hi, @PatricK - I pondered setting up my templates exactly the way you mentioned, but for a number of reasons, that wouldn't be practical for this particular scenario, especially in the cases where they are shared with other users. Good thoughts though, and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you have a network share folder everyone has access to? You can add code to AutoUpdate (with robocopy) when a template is "New"ed. Also, we deploy all the templates to computer's local C:\, to prevent accidental changes to the master copy, only very few people has access to the master copy.

Comment: By names of the macro subs in screenshot, they should all reside on 1 addin. Different template should have a subset if not all, add CustomUI to make it easier to use than manually assign and remember shortcut keys..

Comment: Hi, @PatricK - That screen shot was not intended to illustrate the particular macros that would cause the problem. It was strictly to illustrate that the problem would occur in ANY scenario where a user typed (or caused to be typed via a text expander) a macro name in the macro window that does not exist. There are numerous scenarios where that might occur (in this particular production environment) that cannot be addressed or resolved with global templates or addins. Hard to explain, but just trust me on that. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @PatricK, re your Q about a network share folder, that scenario also would not apply here. These templates and the accompanying text expander glossaries/dictionaries (which will contain many entries invoking various macros) will be distributed to many (as in hundreds, maybe thousands) of users who work from home on a single computer or perhaps with two computers networked or otherwise linked together, but not likely in a scenario where a commonly shared folder would solve this problem. I see where you're going with this, and in a multiuser (in one place) setting, that would work, but not here.

Comment: One more thing, @PatricK, in this scenario, it is a deliberate intention that most, if not all, of the users will have full control over the master copy of the template(s). In fact, they may be creating identical or similar templates on their own and employing some of the same mechanisms, and running into the same issues. So my original mission of finding and deleting empty macros *seems* (for lack of better knowledge) to be the best approach here, if such a method exists.

Answer (score 1):

My inclination would be to offer the users an interface which makes them less likely to run into the problem, such as a series of keyboard shortcuts or Ribbon controls. But I suspect you've already considered that.

It's possible to work with code modules by using the VB Extensibility library (part of Office, but you have to add a reference to **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3** in Tools/References the VBA Editor). This object model is a bit finicky and not well documented. I can't recall having ever seen a discussion about this particular topic in a forum...

This hasn't been tested extensively, but it seems to work in my test environment. It only searches the `NewMacros` module of Normal.dotm as that would be the most common problem in the scenario you describe. You'd need to tweak it to search a different template or document (`ActiveDocument`, `ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate`), but I suspect that won't be a problem for you.

```
'Delete procedures that containt only empty lines,
'Sub, Dim, End Sub and comments    
Sub RemoveEmptyMacros()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.vbComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind

    Dim LineNum As Long
    Dim ProcName As String
    Dim iLineCounter As Long
    Dim iProcStart As Long, iProcNrLines As Long
    Dim sLineContent As String
    Dim isEmpty As Boolean

    'Needed only if you want to log deletions
    Dim Doc As word.Document
    Dim Rng As Range

    'Change this to search something other than Normal.dotm
    Set VBProj = NormalTemplate.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.vbComponents("NewMacros")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
    iLineCounter = 0

    'Needed only if you want to log deletions
    Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    Set Rng = Doc.content

    With CodeMod
        'Start after the declaration section
        LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1

        'Loop all the procedures by going line-by-line
        Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
            'Assume a procedure is empty, if it's not
            'this will be set to false and nothing happens
            isEmpty = True
            ProcName = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)
            iProcStart = .ProcStartLine(ProcName, ProcKind)
            iProcNrLines = .ProcCountLines(ProcName, ProcKind)

            'Check all lines whether empty, sub, dim, end, comment
            'OR have content
            For iLineCounter = iProcStart To iProcStart + iProcNrLines
                sLineContent = .Lines(iLineCounter, 1)
                If Len(sLineContent) > 0 Then
                    'if there's content, procedure is not empty
                    'leave the FOR loop without deleting
                    If Left(Trim(sLineContent), 1) <> "'" And _
                        Left(Trim(sLineContent), 3) <> "Sub" And _
                        Left(Trim(sLineContent), 3) <> "End" Then
                            isEmpty = False
                            Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            'Increment line number to start of next procedure
            'for next DO loop
            LineNum = iProcStart + iProcNrLines + 1
            'If you want a list of all procedures in the Immediate Window
            'Debug.Print ProcName

            If isEmpty Then
                'If you want to log a list of the subs that were deleted
                'Rng.Text = ProcName & vbCr
                'Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                .DeleteLines iProcStart, iProcNrLines
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub

Function ProcKindString(ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind) As String
    Select Case ProcKind
        Case vbext_pk_Get
            ProcKindString = "Property Get"
        Case vbext_pk_Let
            ProcKindString = "Property Let"
        Case vbext_pk_Set
            ProcKindString = "Property Set"
        Case vbext_pk_Proc
            ProcKindString = "Sub Or Function"
        Case Else
            ProcKindString = "Unknown Type: " & CStr(ProcKind)
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, @CindyMeister. I will definitely give this a try! Thanks so much for sticking with me on this troubleshooting mission - much appreciated. I will have many macros assigned to keyboard shortcuts - I'm a big fan of that. But I also strongly believe shortcuts should be used judiciously, because they are not limitless. And careful consideration needs to be given when they are assigned to specific templates or documents to be shared with others.

Many of these macros fall into a category that makes sense to  simply access them from the macro list. I will give this a try. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @HappyNanaMO I completely understand. In the old days of custom toolbars, that would have been ideal. One thing you *could* look at would be to incorporate them in Custom Ribbon UI as part of the right-click menu, maybe separated into lists under menu points (categorize them?).

Comment: oh, how I MISS the toolbars! I actually do have several custom tabs on my ribbon, as well as a few macros on the QAT, and will be encouraging other users to add them as well, when it makes sense to do so. Unfortunately, the ribbon is not as easy to manage, so it can't cover every single situation. I sure wish it were more user-friendly to share the ribbon, as it is in the WordPerfect world. But yes, I do incorporate custom ribbon tabs quite often. 

But even with all the customization options, there will always be a few orphan macros who live only in the macro list. ~Karen :)